# Parsing commands CLI program Python

Tags: python, parsing, command-line

I used to write my (simple) Python programs in Python 2, but it seems that Python 3 is quite mature. I now have a CLI program called `ratjuice.py` and when I execute it the program asks for a command input (which I have made some tab completion thing for).

So I might have commands like `html` which could output the subcommands like `parse` or `destroy`. I might want to use the command `html parse rat.html`. So I am looking for a Python module which allows me to parse this input based on a *white list*. So I would basically tell what is allowed and the rest is ignored or rejected (I might forget some things if I sanitize the input...)

Is there any *good* way to do this other than mere string manipulation?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [cmd](http://docs.python.org/library/cmd.html) module.  It does line-editing and remembers history (supposedly).

Answer (score 1):

A string parsing version I just slapped together that requires no additional libraries, that works with your "whitelist" idea:

```
def foo1(bar):
   print '1. ' + bar

def foo2(bar):
   print '2. ' + bar

def foo3(bar):
   print '3. ' + bar

cmds = {
   'html': {
      'parse': foo1,
      'dump': foo2,
      'read': {
         'file': foo3,
      }
   }
}

def argparse(cmd):
   cmd = cmd.strip()
   cmdsLevel = cmds
   while True:
      candidate = [key for key in cmdsLevel.keys() if cmd.startswith(key)]
      if not candidate:
         print "Failure"
         break

      cmdsLevel = cmdsLevel[candidate[0]]
      cmd = cmd[len(candidate[0]):].strip()

      if not isinstance(cmdsLevel, dict):
         cmdsLevel(cmd)
         break


argparse('html parse rat.html')
argparse('foo')
argparse('html read file rat.html')
argparse('html dump rat.html')
```